# Ask about other games like Go?

Tags: discussion

Go is similar to chess in many respects and is played by over a billion people.

Would it make sense to include "igo" as it known in Japan (baduk in Korean) as a question subject?

I realize that chess experts may not be able to answer go questions and vice versa, but this is no different than any other SE site. For example, when somebody asks about Ruby or XML on Stack Overflow I cannot answer, but if they ask about Java or C, I can.

Answer (score 8):

Board games are already on topic at [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/). In particular, [Go is the 8th most popular tag there](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go). Splitting the Go community between two sites wouldn't be useful.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't realize that.